# How to create custom bundle of "User" entity using GUI?

Tags: 7, users, entities

Is it possible to create custom bundle from "user" entity without programming? Only using drupal administration? Are there any modules that could help to create such bundles?

I would like to achieve, that some user roles would have custom fields. I have found [this module](https://drupal.org/project/user_role_field) for creating fields per user role, but maybe it would be better to create custom user bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same requirement recently and was able to achieve this using the Profile2 module.  Basically you set up profiles and add custom fields to that particular profile.  Then you create a user using that profile.  Works great but if you are pulling a view of these you must reference the profile in a relationship.

Profile2
https://drupal.org/project/profile2

Comment: Also you can set each profile to be set to a particular role upon creation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to restrict certain fields to particular user roles then [Field Permission](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module is the perfect one.

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>   field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

If you want to group certain fields under user entity then you might be looking for [Profile2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2) module.

> The module is aimed to provide a simple, but extensible solution
>   providing a similar end user interface like the core profile module by
>   default. Multiple profile types may be created via the UI (e.g. a
>   general profile + a customer profile), whereas the module provides
>   separated permissions for those.